# How can I create a navigation history in VB

Tags: vb.net

Sorry if this is a bad question. Very first time ever using SO/any SE site.
I tried searching for a lot of visual basic questions related to buttons, navigation, etc. and didn't find what I was looking for.

```
    Private Sub NextButton_Click(sender As Object, _
                             e As EventArgs) Handles NextButton.Click
    Try
        If OptionText.Checked = True And OptionTextBox.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Custom text may not be blank.")
        ElseIf OptionText.Checked = True Then
            If Not OptionTextBox.Text Is Nothing Then
                c.Add(OptionTextBox.Text)
            End If
        ElseIf Option1.Checked = True Then : c.Add(CStr(1))
        ElseIf Option2.Checked = True Then : c.Add(CStr(2))
        End If
        cnum = c.Count + 1
        TopBox()
        DebugPrintCList()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print("Error in nextbutton")
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is the code of a next button I have, and I have an almost identical piece of code for back button except it removes the last item in the list and makes a textbox equal to that value.

What I want to do is have a series of buttons, possibly a drop down list, where I can click a button and have a different set of buttons appear, click one of those, and have a different set of buttons appear.
I want to be able to back track up the list and remember the choices I made previous to the last choice.

In a simple form I can do this with my current program and a `List(Of String)` but I want to have different buttons appear, instead of repeatedly choosing from radiobuttons or typing in strings.

I did this before with a number of variables, and I just recently edited my program to work with lists, but it still doesn't change the layout of the form, just remembers the previous values.

My question is how can I use a list to store a navigation history and change the layout of the form. I don't want separate forms and I'd prefer not to have a bunch of panels that I toggle the visibility of.

Comment: Use an undo framework such as https://undo.codeplex.com/. Store whatever state you wish in it and restore it whenever you undo/redo.

Comment: Sorry if this is an obvious question but I'm experimenting with lists and I have a List(of List(Of String)) how do I see the names of lists inside the top-level list?
IE: tools as List(of List(of String)) contains the lists "tool1" "tool2" "tool3" which all contain 4 strings. How do I see the name of the list at tools(0)